# Given a sequence n elements, A1, A2, ..., An. Remove the least amount of digits to make array non-decreasing

Tags: algorithm, math

Given a sequence n elements, A<sub>1</sub>, A<sub>2</sub>,..., A<sub>n</sub>

- n ≤ 1000
- Let ndigits(x) is amount of digits of x

  - For example:
  - ndigits(10000) = 5
  - ndigits(123) = 3
  - ndigits(9) = 1
- It is guaranteed that sum of ndigits(A<sub>i</sub>) ≤ 10<sup>5</sup> where 1 ≤ i ≤ n.

  - which means ndigits(A<sub>1</sub>) + ndigits(A<sub>2</sub>) + ... + ndigits(A<sub>n</sub>) ≤ 10<sup>5</sup>

Remove the least amount of digits to make the sequence non-decreasing. 
Print the number of digits has been removed.

For example:

- n = 4
- A = [93, 31, 23, 31]
- Delete the bold digits to make the sequence non-decreasing:
- A = [**9**3, 3**1**, 23, 31] → A = [3, 3, 23, 31]
- The answer is 2 (delete two digits 1 and 9)

I have attempted with naive algorithm:

- For every elements from n-1 to 1, let that element A<sub>i</sub>, remove least amount of digits to make that elements largest but smaller than the A<sub>i+1</sub> (***)
- Use bruteforce and check the condition (***) (which take O(2<sup>sum of ndigits</sup>) time).

Is there any better algorithm ?

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved using dynamic programming.

Lets first figure out how to remove digits. Use a binary number and depending on the position of `1` remove the digit in that position in the given number. An example will make things clear:

*Delete-masking a number by `j` :*

Let `j = 2` - its binary representation is `10`, you delete the number at the position where it is `1`. For example for the number `93` delete-masking it with `2` will yield `3`, delete-masking it with `3` will yield `93` itself because you cannot delete all the numbers ! delete-masking it with `1` will yield `9`. I hope you get the idea.

*Range of `j`:*

The range of `j` will be only from `0` to `63`, because the biggest number in your input is `10^5` and has only `6` digits atmost and the largest length of a binary number with `6` digits is `63`.

*Algorithm:*

Let `dp[i-1][j]` represent the number of deletions that are required to make a non-decreasing subsequence when the `(i-1)`th number is delete-masked by a number `j`. If its not possible to make a non decreasing- it is something like `MAX_VALUE`

*Update `dp[i][j]`:*

Now to get `dp[i][j]` you need to compare all `dp[i-1][k]` with `dp[i][j]` and update as follows:

```
for j = 0 to 63:
    if (length of binary representation of j <= length of the ith number ):
       dp[i][j] = MAX_VALUE
       for all k = 0 to 63:
          if dp[i-1][k] != MAX and (ith number after delete-masking with j) >= (i-1th number after delete-masking with k) : 
          dp[i][j] = min(dp[i][j], dp[i-1][k] + (bitcount of j))
```

You get these values all the way upto `arr.length-1` and then you take the minimum of all `dp[arr.length-1][j]` for `j = 0 to 63`

Base condition is :
If input array length is more than 1 :

`dp[0][j] = (bitcount of j) if length of binary representation of j <= length of the number arr[0]`

A working example is shown [here](https://repl.it/repls/MemorableWiltedRule)

Comment: your answer is so great, but maybe you misunderstanded, you wrote that "because the biggest number in your input is 10^5", actually my biggest number has 10^5 digits, which means it could be 10^(10^5)

Comment: @null no that's not right. you said *It is guaranteed that sum of ndigits(Ai) ≤ 105 where 1 ≤ i ≤ n.

    which means ndigits(A1) + ndigits(A2) + ... + ndigits(An) ≤ 105* now figure out what could be the biggest number if that statement is valid.

Comment: - ndigits(x) is the number of digits x (the amount of digits of x). for example: ndigits(10000) = 5, ndigits(9) = 1

- this is an example: n = 1000, A[1] = 1, A[2] = 1, A[3] = 1, ..., A[999] = 1, A[1000] = 100..0 (10^5 - 1000 digits "0", which is very large, not 63 digits). ndigits(A1) = 1, ndigits(A2) = 1, ..., ndigits(A999) = 1, ndigits(A1000) = 10^5 - 1000. Sum of ndigits(Ai) where 1 <= i <= n is 1 + 1 + ... + 1 + 10^5 - 1000 = 10^5

Comment: I have edited my post and give example what ndigits is.